# Android support v7 library gives bunch of missing resources error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

When I open eclipse (and I have the `android-support-v7-appcompat` library imported), I get this errors in the console:

Does anyone know how to fix this
?

Thanks

These are about 40% of the total errors.

```
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:61: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-10-29 13:38:07 - project] C:\Users\Me\Documents\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
```

Answer (score 1):

change into your `AndroidManifest.xml` the property `android:targetSdkVersion` to `"21"`

```
android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

then clean the project, `Project` -> `Clean`